# Pytest how to call a function with fixture argument directly

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, pytest

I am building a test suite for a web app. I am using fixtures as below:

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from common import Common

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def driver(module, headless=True):
    opts = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    opts.add_argument('--headless') if headless else None
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts)
    driver.get('http://localhost:8080/request')
    yield driver
    driver.quit()

def test_title(driver):
    assert driver.title == 'abc'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_title() #what I need to execute to see if everything is fine
```

Suppose I need to see if my `test_title` function is doing what it needs to by running this module directly inside a `if __name__ == '__main__':`. How can I call `test_title()` with driver passed in as an argument?

calling `test_title` like below:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_title(driver(None, False))
```

python produces an error mentioned below:

```
(virtual) sflash@debian:~/Documents/php/ufj/ufj-test$ ./test_r*
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_request.py", line 30, in <module>
    test_empty_all(driver(None, headless=True))
  File "/home/sflash/Documents/php/ufj/ufj-test/virtual/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/fixtures.py", line 1176, in result
    fail(message, pytrace=False)
  File "/home/sflash/Documents/php/ufj/ufj-test/virtual/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/outcomes.py", line 153, in fail
    raise Failed(msg=msg, pytrace=pytrace)
Failed: Fixture "driver" called directly. Fixtures are not meant to be called directly,
but are created automatically when test functions request them as parameters.
See https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html for more information about fixtures, and
https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/deprecations.html#calling-fixtures-directly about how to update your code.
```

Comment: Pytest tests are supposed to be executed by calling pytest on the command line. You can call `pytest.main()` (with the command line options as arguments), but that would do exactly the same as calling pytest directly (e.g. collect all tests, regardless if they are in the current module).

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I didn't know that, thanks! But there are many other ways to solve this like directly creating another driver in main. But I want to know if there is a way to run this with python interpreter directly in the old fashioned way.

Comment: Well, calling `python -m pytest` (or `python -m pytest test_xxx.py` if you want to run only a specific test) would do what you want, unless I don't understand you correctly.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen sorry, I need to run it directly, as in "./test_request.py" or ("python3 test_request.py"). This is more or less a question of curiosity, if whether it is possible to call and send `driver` to `test_title` only by changing source code by changing fixture behavior.

Comment: Well, as I wrote, you could put `pytest,main()` in your `__main__` part, that would do the same as calling it via pytest on the commandline.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen its essentially what I don't want to do. I prefaced this question around calling and passing `driver` directly to `test_title` in main. Not using pytest ( I intentionally isolate pytest out to do process of elimination if a bug appears in my test case )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226764/discussion-between-silver-flash-and-mrbean-bremen).

Comment: If you don't want to use `pytest`, you shouldn't be using `pytest` features in the first place, including fixtures. `@pytest.fixture` makes no sense outside of a test execution. The invocation of `pytest.main` as suggested by @MrBeanBremen _is_ the proper answer to this. You can still run your script via `./myscript.py` or however you want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As has been discussed in the comments, fixtures cannot be called directly - they only work together with `pytest`.

To invoke the test directly from your code, you can call `pytest.main()` in your `__main__` section, which has the same effect as calling `pytest` on the command line. Any command line options can be added as arguments to the call (as a list), for example:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pytest.main(['-vv', 'test.py::test_title'])
```

To use the driver *without* involving pytest (which was your intention) you have to extract the driver logic and call it separately both from the fixture and from main:

```py
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from common import Common

def get_driver(headless=True):
    opts = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    opts.add_argument('--headless') if headless else None
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts)
    driver.get('http://localhost:8080/request')
    return driver
):

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def driver():
    yield get_driver()
    driver.quit()

def test_title(driver):
    assert driver.title == 'abc'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = get_driver()
    test_title(driver) 
    driver.quit()
```

Note that this only works if the test function does not rely on any pytest-specific stuff (for example auto-applied fixtures).
Note also that you cannot use a parameter in your fixture as you did in your example, as you have no way to provide the parameter. Instead you can use [parametrized fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html#fixture-parametrize).

Comment: I would add the invocation of `pytest.main` at the beginning of this answer to point future readers to the correct solution.

Comment: I am a complete newbie. In the definition of driver() function, where is "module" argument coming from? I don't see any definition of module as a fixture.
I have the same question with the request argument herehttps://github.com/GokuMohandas/Made-With-ML/blob/540754392af9f49e637b491009586a61c54e2268/tests/model/conftest.py#L12

Comment: It had been in the question, so I assumed it is some fixture that is defined elsewhere. But I agree that it may be confusing here, and as it is not needed for the example, I now removed it. The request argument OTOH is a documented fixture in pytest.

Comment: Thank you for your response. IT answers both of my questions